# I have a breadcrumb and I would like to set last breadcrumb should cover the empty space

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

[image: Breadcrumb]

I have a breadcrumb and I would like to set **last breadcrumb** should cover the empty space

`max-width` sets for only limited words should show, but for last breadcrumb should show until browser width.

Note: If text is big should not show full text, it should end in same line. And it should work dynamically, if breadcrumb title changed should work correctly

Is there any way to fix this using `last-child`?

```css
.breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

ol.breadcrumb.training-breadcrumb li.breadcrumb-item {
  display: block;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<ol class="breadcrumb training-breadcrumb">
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">HTML</li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">Breadcrumb Breadcrumb Breadcrumb</li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">High brightness and opacity</li>
  <li class="breadcrumb-item">Last breadcrumb Last breadcrumb Last breadcrumb </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.breadcrumb-item:nth-last-child(1){
  max-width: 100%!important;
}
```

You will need to add something like this. 
".breadcrumb-item:nth-last-child(1)" refers to the last element with the class "breadcrumb-item". 
Usually you don't need the !important tag but somehow it didn't work without...

Comment: i have tried this but it went to separate line, 

as per my requirements, it shouldn't go to another line it should end in same line.

Comment: https://codepen.io/luis-zuniga/pen/zYdKwzM It works for me on codepen. Maybe the parent element has a smaller width?

Comment: if you add more text you can note that it will get into separate line,

 only li had max-width: 300px;